# Control access to web apps on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I currently have numerous web apps which are just webapi's on Azure. I have a gateway web app that is accessible publically as it has its own authentication mechanisms.

However the other web apps I don't want to be accessed publically, only the gateway web app should have access to these API's and possibly my dev machine just to test they are running and operational.

What is the best way to do this on Azure?

Comment: Have you looked into API Apps? The scenario you describe almost perfectly matches the capabilities offered there.

Comment: Hiding away in the new portal, I should really stay switched over to that. It looks very promising. But where abouts in the config of an API app do I configure permissions of 1 API to only be accessible via other API's in that resource group?

Comment: Open the API App blade > All Settings -> Application Settings. You'll see the option there. It has to be set to "Internal". There is a step by step guide here http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-add-authentication/

Comment: Thanks. If you want to put that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't looked into API Apps, you will find a lot of functionality already existing there. For example, limiting the visibility of the API App is as simple as going to the API App blade -> All Settings -> Application Settings and setting the Visibility to "Internal". This will make the API App only accessible within the same Resource Group

You can find more information [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-add-authentication/)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have web apps you can use Azure Active Directory (AAD) to configure authentication.

A tutorial on how to do so is here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/waws/archive/2015/04/20/how-i-to-setup-azure-active-directory-with-a-web-app.aspx